# navigating to an anchor when editing a row in datable with jsf

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable

(Using jsf-2)

I have a dataTable with one column which can be edited:

```
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Label" style="font-weight: bold">
                </h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{m.author2displayed}" rendered="#{m.editable}" size="10"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{m.author2displayed}" rendered="#{not m.editable}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="save edits" rendered="#{m.editable}" onclick="submit()" action ="#{finalCheckBean.saveedits()}"/>
        </h:column>
```

When I click on "save edits", we stay on the same view and that's the desired effect (finalCheckBean.saveedits() returns null).

Problem: the browser scrolls all back to the top of the page, whereas I'd like that the page stays displayed at the level of the row just edited. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already using JSF2, just bring in some ajax magic using `<f:ajax>` in the command button. Wrap the to-be-executed and rendered components in a common component and reference it in `execute` and `render` of `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Label" style="font-weight: bold" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:panelGroup id="author2displayed">
        <h:inputText value="#{m.author2displayed}" rendered="#{m.editable}" size="10"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{m.author2displayed}" rendered="#{not m.editable}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="save edits" rendered="#{m.editable}" onclick="submit()" action="#{finalCheckBean.saveedits()}">
            <f:ajax execute="author2displayed" render="author2displayed" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:column>
```

This way the scroll position will remain unchanged (provided that you still return `null` or `void` from the action method).

Comment: this works but now my rendering of components is not synchronized anymore - time for another question I am afraid...

Comment: It was just a kickoff example, based on guesses on the code provided so far. The concrete functional requirement for this output, input and button was namely nowhere stated in the question. At least, you can control in `execute` attribute which inputs needs to be processed and in `render` attribute which components needs to be updated. They can take a spaceseparated string of multiple client IDs. Note that the backing bean must be view scoped in order to live as long as the view lives (but based on your previous questions you already know this)